# How git fork actually works?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I would like to ask how the git fork is actually working in a git server. For example in gitlab, when a user forks a repository then the files of the project are actually copied or there is a link(symbolic) with the main repository? To put it differently, are the same files stored (into database) N times, one for each fork? If yes, isn't it a waste of hard disk space?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while interesting, it's purely pedagogical and doesn't represent _a specific problem that can be solved._

Comment: Attempting to read the documentation for `git-fork` yields `No manual entry for git-fork`; git doesn't know anything about forking.  The details of how gitlab implements what it calls a "fork" will depend on gitlab.  It will be different for github.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, "When a user forks a repository then the files of the project are actually copied or there is a link(symbolic) with the main repository?" A fork is a copy of a repository, not just a link. The same files are stored.

To answer the second part of your question, "If yes, is this not a waste of hard disk space?" This is not exactly a question with a direct answer but I can offer my 2 cents. Generally I consider the decentralized component of git to be one of its strengths. If you lose your remote repository on GitHub or GitLab, as long as your developers are pulling frequently you may not lose a whole lot. It also allows multiple developers to concurrently experiment with changes and add features without affecting code that might be production only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Therefore, there is no something smart to avoid storing of the file multiple times on the database. I am looking for a solution to store the same files of multiple users once (in one place) and save only the files that each users changes (to a his local folder).

Comment: If you mean on a _single_ database (a single repo), the objects are stored (by their content) _once_ and never duplicate (only on packaged files... but it's a corner case)... so a file can be renamed 1000 times.... be added and deleted over and over... and it will be stored only once on the database and have thousands of pointers to it.

Comment: I am not that I understood your answer. Forget gitlab, lets say that I have a system with multiple users where all the users at the starting point have the same 10 files. I would like to store these files once. One simple solutions is to make symbolic links for each file in the user local folder. However, I would like if a user changes one of this files to save only this (delele the symbolic link) and keep the rest 9 with symbolic links (to his local folder). This is a pretty simple solution and I am wondering if there is something more clever. Thus, I am looking to similar implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there is any special deduplication between forks, and if so, *how* there is deduplication between forks, is partly up to the server.  Git provides several mechanisms, such as the environment variable `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` and the file `objects/info/alternates`.  See [the top level documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) and [the git repository layout documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) for details.  When using this method, *be careful;* heed the warnings in the documentation.

Remember that as far as Git itself is concerned, a fork is just a clone: the server records some additional information behind Git's back (even if it uses Git's mechanisms to do this), to make "fork" have additional value over plain clone, but Git itself remains blissfully unaware of this extra information.  If the cloning process uses a local path (not `file://` and not a host-based URL), Git will by default attempt to use hard links to share objects and/or pack files.  This kind of sharing is generally safe and requires no special care.  It's visible to Git but Git does not need to be aware of it beyond the initial hard-link process.

Besides these techniques, the underlying operating system may provide deduplication methods for files and/or for block storage.  These, if present, are invisible to Git itself.  They require no special care when using Git.  They generally use more computing power to discover such duplication, and may be complicated to administer, but that all happens at the OS level.

Comment: Thank you but I am not interested for git as git. I would like to know how a git server is working e.g. gitlab. If a user forks a project then are the files copied to the particular user storage space? I am talking only for remote repositories. Forget local repositories.

Comment: @user2277314 Only the people who write and/or run Gitlab servers can answer Gitlab questions. Only the people who run GitHub can answer GitHub questions. I can only answer Git questions (and you could too, because the source for Git is public, unlike the source for the proprietary parts backing GitHub). As you can see from the answers and comments you have gotten so far, your question is just not going to get you the answers you seek.

Comment: I understand thank you. I am just asking if you have any clue.